# specific node from xml java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

My xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <metadonnees>
        <usine type="usine-matiere">
            <icones>
                <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UMP0%.png"/>
                <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UMP33%.png"/>
                <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UMP66%.png"/>
                <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UMP100%.png"/>
            </icones>
            <sortie type = "metal"/>
            <interval-production>100</interval-production>
        </usine>
        <usine type="usine-aile">
            <icones>
                <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UT0%.png"/>
                <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UT33%.png"/>
                <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UT66%.png"/>
                <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UT100%.png"/>
            </icones>
            <entree type="metal" quantite="2"/>
            <sortie type="aile"/>
            <interval-production>50</interval-production>
        </usine>
        <usine type="usine-moteur">
            <icones>            
                <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UM0%.png"/>
                <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UM33%.png"/>
                <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UM66%.png"/>
                <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UM100%.png"/>
            </icones>
            <entree type="metal" quantite="4"/>
            <sortie type="moteur"/>
            <interval-production>75</interval-production>
        </usine>
        <usine type="usine-assemblage">
            <icones>
                <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/UA0%.png"/>
                <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/UA33%.png"/>
                <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/UA66%.png"/>
                <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/UA100%.png"/>
            </icones>
            <entree type="aile" quantite="2"/>
            <entree type="moteur" quantite="4"/>
            <sortie type="avion"/>
            <interval-production>110</interval-production>
        </usine>
        <usine type="entrepot">
            <icones>
                <icone type="vide" path="src/ressources/E0%.png"/>
                <icone type="un-tiers" path="src/ressources/E33%.png"/>
                <icone type="deux-tiers" path="src/ressources/E66%.png"/>
                <icone type="plein" path="src/ressources/E100%.png"/>
            </icones>
            <entree type="avion" capacite="5"/>
        </usine>
    </metadonnees>

    <simulation>
        <usine type="usine-matiere" id="11" x="32" y="32"/>
        <usine type="usine-aile" id="21" x="320" y="32"/>
        <usine type="usine-assemblage" id="41" x="160" y="192"/> 
        <usine type="entrepot" id="51" x="640" y="192"/>
        <usine type="usine-matiere" id="13" x="544" y="576"/>
        <usine type="usine-matiere" id="12" x="96" y="352"/>
        <usine type="usine-moteur" id="31" x="320" y="352"/>
        <chemins>
            <chemin de="11" vers="21" />
            <chemin de="21" vers="41" />
            <chemin de="41" vers="51" />
            <chemin de="12" vers="31" />
            <chemin de="13" vers="31" />
            <chemin de="31" vers="41" />
        </chemins>
    </simulation>

</configuration>
```

and my code is this:

```
public class mainTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String url = "C:\\Users\\ladin\\eclipse-workspace\\TP1_LOG121\\src\\ressources\\configuration.xml";
        
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            
            Document doc = db.parse(new File(url));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            
            System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            
            
            
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("usine");
            NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("icone");
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node p = (Node) nList.item(i);
        
                
                
                
                if(p.getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element usine = (Element) p;
                    
                    System.out.println(usine.getAttribute("type"));
                    
                
                }
                
                
                
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0 ; j< nList2.getLength() ; j++) {
                Node p2 = nList2.item(j);
                
                if(p2.getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element icone = (Element) p2;
                    
                    System.out.println("état de l'usine : " + icone.getAttribute("type"));
                    System.out.println("chemin de la photo : " + icone.getAttribute("path"));
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                }
                
            }
            
            
    
            
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

I only want to get data from my simulation list, but when I run my code, I got this

- Root element: configuration
- usine-matiere --> from metadonnees
- usine-aile --> from metadonnees
- usine-moteur --> from metadonnes
- usine-assemblage --> from metadonnes
- entrepot --> from metadonnes
- usine-matiere --> from simulation
- usine-aile --> from simulation
- usine-assemblage --> from simulation
- entrepot --> from simulation
- usine-matiere --> from simulation
- usine-matiere --> from simulation
- usine-moteur --> from simulation

like I said, I only want the data from "simulation" and not "metadonnes".

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are iterating from top to bottom, where your top node is the configuration node. To achieve your goal, you have to something like that:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("simulation"); // finds your simulation tag
```

And then you have to iterate through it.

Comment: i alreydy did it, but when i'm in the loop, the value is null